# using jQuery UI Datepicker in MVC razor getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-2) example to use `jQuery UI Datepicker in my MVC project.`

Model

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
```

Razor

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Then as per tutorial created Date helper and pasted this line

```
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", (string)Model.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datefield", @type = "date" })
```

When i run the application, i get run time exception for above line. Model is null. I am not sure why? and How does it bind to my model?

> Additional information: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null
>   reference

DatePickerReady.js

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    $(function () {
        $(".datefield").datepicker();
    });
}
```

Comment: Because `Model` is `null` and you cannot call `.ToShortDateString()` on `null` - just remove `(string)Model.ToShortDateString())` from the `TextBox()` methd. (and adding `@type = "date"` in the view and `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` is pointless if your using a jquery datepicker).

Comment: But you do not need an `EditorTemplate` for this. Just replace `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestDate)` with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.RequestDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "datefield" })`

Comment: And you using the wrong overload of `TextBox()` anyway - the 3rd parameter is the format string - [refer docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary{System.String,System.Object}%29)

Comment: But the toturial suggest to do that what you are suggesting not do. Can u go to link in my question and see please.

Comment: That tutorial is just explaining in very simplified examples of how you can use DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates. It has nothing to do with what your trying to acheive

Comment: So how i can achieve 'Use jQuery DatePicker in razor view' in very nice way? Do you have some link to share or may be you can explain as an answer?

Comment: Just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.RequestDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "datefield" })` and `$(".datefield").datepicker();` - but not `if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {` - that means in Chrome and Edge you generating the browsers HTML5 datepicker, not the jquery-ui datepicker (and they need different formats for a start so your code would not bind correctly)

Comment: And its crazy to create an EditorTemplate that just generates what the default template will generate. Use them for complex types, or if yo want to include extra html, but not just to generate the input

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the casting part of `(string)Model.ToShortDateString()`, no need for the casting here as the `ToShortDateString` will return a `string` anyways. Try this instead:

```
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()),
    new { @class = "datefield", @type = "date" })
```

And you need to make sure to name your editor template a name matching your data type (DateTime.cshtml in your case) or use the `UIHint` attribute if you like to customize the name, and make sure you add your template under the proper `EditorTemplates` folder.

Comment: Should i try above line in addition to what i did? Do i still need to keep editorTemplate which is causing problem? All i want to use jQuery DatePicker in my razor view

Comment: The above line is the replacement of the content of your `EditorTemplate`. Using editor templates is a good practice that will enhance your codes maintainability and reuseability, keep using them :)